# How exactly does this Jaccard distance logic (get_jaccarddist) in FFmpeg work?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I see [this C code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/signature_lookup.c) in FFmpeg source `signature_lookup` file for Jaccard distance in method `get_jaccarddist`.

If you see in the code below that is calculating for 5 BagOfWords.

Now for two BagOfWords with say nothing in common intersection would be 0, that means `jaccarddist` would be 0, so ideally its a bad pair but this if condition `jaccarddist >= sc->thworddist`, would be false isn't it but we want it to be true as its bad pair?

What are the default values of `sc->thworddist`?

Also surprised why `jaccarddist` is int and not float/double?

```c
/**
 * calculates the jaccard distance and evaluates a pair of coarse signatures as good
 * @return 0 if pair is bad, 1 otherwise
 */
static int get_jaccarddist(SignatureContext *sc, CoarseSignature *first, CoarseSignature *second)
{
    int jaccarddist, i, composdist = 0, cwthcount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if ((jaccarddist = intersection_word(first->data[i], second->data[i])) > 0) {
            jaccarddist /= union_word(first->data[i], second->data[i]);
        }
        if (jaccarddist >= sc->thworddist) {
            if (++cwthcount > 2) {
                /* more than half (5/2) of distances are too wide */
                return 0;
            }
        }
        composdist += jaccarddist;
        if (composdist > sc->thcomposdist) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```